# Center logo in html5 boilerplate

Tags: css, boilerplate, html5boilerplate

I'm using [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and their .ir class. I made the logo clickable, I want to center it in the page but so far no luck. I tried margin: 0 auto; and text-align: center; but they both don't seem to work.

The html

```
   <a href="/"><h1 class="ir">logo header</h1></a>
```

and the css

```
    h1 {
    height: 373px;
    }

    .ir {
    display: block;
    border: 0; 
    text-indent: -999em; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: transparent; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    text-align: left; 
    direction: ltr; 
    *line-height: 0; 
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/yYnyJ.jpg);
    }
    .ir br { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `background-postion: center;` to the rule. You might want to use `top center` as the value, if you want the align image at the top and centered at the same time.

<sub>**Note::** The image size have to be subsequently smaller than the `<h1>` to appear on the center.</sub>

Moreover, I would recommend using the shorthand property as well.

```
.ir {
    display: block;
    border: 0; 
    text-indent: -999em; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-align: left; 
    direction: ltr; 
    *line-height: 0; 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/yYnyJ.jpg) transparent no-repeat center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We do not recommend you add your styles to the helper classes directly. This means you cannot reuse them for other cases where you need the `.ir` class again (if you have another background to replace). Please add a classname to the markup you want to replace with image in addition to the class called `ir` like this:

```
<h2 class="ir myh2classname"></h2>
```

and then add your background like so:

```
.myh2classname {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/yYnyJ.jpg) transparent no-repeat center;
}
```

This way if you have another image you want to use as a background to some other section, all you need to do is to add another classname to that section's markup:

```
  <h3 class="ir anotherimagereplacement"></h3>
```

and then add your background for the other section like this:

```
   .anotherimagereplacement {
        background: url(path/to/image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in .ir

```
background-position: center center;
```